# Join mongodb collections by ObjectId in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have following model:

```
public class PaymentPlan
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string PlanName { get; set; }
        ...
    }

public class Payment
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public string _id { get; set; }
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string PaymentPlanId { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

And trying a simple join as follows

```
 var joinedData = (from payment in PaymentCollection.AsQueryable()
                                 join paymentPlan in PaymentPlanCollection
                                 on payment.PaymentPlanId equals paymentPlan._id
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Payment = payment,
                                     PaymentPlan = paymentPlan
                                 }).ToList();
```

Documents exists in both collections with matching _id, however join is returning 0 results, what is wrong with my code? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Sound weird, can you confirm that the `PaymentPlanId` is stored as `ObjectId` type in Payment collection? Ensure that both fields have the same type so you can compare it correctly.

Comment: It is confirmed, this is an actual document in the payment collection:


_id: 64ed3eb5df7362a59684d7c8 <- ObjectId type
IdAlumno: "AUSNtqgjBk"
PaymentPlanId: 64debe152a0938ce38fcaa91 <- ObjectId type

Comment: Tried in my local side to reproduce, but it works fine. If LINQ way not working, maybe you can try to write an aggregation query and execute to see whether there is data returned. Note that, unsure what is your `PaymentPlanCollection`, from my side I modify it to `PaymentPlanCollection.AsQueryable()`

Comment: It´s set as asQueryable on declaration, so that should not be the issue (I modified it anyway to keep consistency), any other changes you made?

Comment: Found the error!, I was looking in the wrong place. There was a typo on collection name, when declaring PaymentPlanCollection variable. So the collection did not exist, so it was not throwing any error but was finding no results!, I checked the code multiple times but was not paying attention to collection name assuming it was right. thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Code works fine, issue was on variable declaration:

```
var PaymentPlanCollection = session.Client.GetDatabase("Schools").GetCollection<PaymentPlan>("PaymentPlan");
```

There was a type in "PaymentPlan" collection name